# Fix an error in an objective c tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm on [this step](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html) of the "Your First iOS Application" tutorial from Apple.

However, the line `[self setMyViewController:aViewController];` has an error and the app appears as a blank black screen. The error message is `'HelloWorldAppDelegate' may not respond to '-setMyViewController' (2)`

I've been following the tutorial carefully. How can I make this error go away? Why is it so ambiguous (it "may" not respond? under what circumstances will it?) and why am I getting this error in the first place? What step did I miss?

Comment: we would need waaaay more context to debug this problem, maybe even post all of HelloWorldAppDelegate.{h,m}. Have you compared your version with that in the tutorial line by line? It's probably a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your header-file and add `- (void)setMyViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;`

Maybe you need to rename the parameter.

And btw. it's a warning not an error. Warnings are just for signalize that it could have problems if you haven't included the method.

If you declare a method in your .h file, the .m file gives out a warning if it isn't included. Don't worry it's not wrong if you forgot to declare a method in your .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your code right after following that step? You should hold off doing so until you have finished following all steps on the page.

The **Housekeeping** section lists a step that you have to follow in order to make your property setter work:

> - In the `@implementation` block of the class, tell the compiler to synthesize the accessor methods for the view controller:
>
>   ```
>     @synthesize myViewController;
>   ```

After you finish adding the code as described by that section, running your code should work. If not, check your imports and your `HelloWorldAppDelegate.h` file — you may have missed something else too like declaring your `@property`.

> Why is it so ambiguous (it "may" not respond? under what circumstances will it?)

It will respond if the compiler can find an implementation of the method, and the method is declared in the header file (unless it's a property accessor), and work as normal. If it does not, your program crashes.

> and why am I getting this error in the first place?

You typically get that warning (it's not an error) if the property is not synthesized. By synthesizing it, the compiler creates the `myViewController` and `setMyViewController:` accessor methods in order for your code to access that property.

Comment: I had completed all steps on that page. The `@synthesize` call is there, everything that should have been imported was imported, and I did declare the `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a warning not an error.

Take heed of warnings, and you're right to want to eliminate them, but the code will compile and may run with warnings.

The warning could be occurring because there isn't a prototype for the method setMyViewController before it is referenced.  The prototype is usually defined in the associated header '.h' file.

The prototype looks like the entry line of the method, up to, but not including the first '{', and with a ';' on the end.

Adding a prototype allows the compiler to verify you're calling the method correctly (and just as importantly, you typed it correctly ;-)

Comment: So a prototype is like a method signature without any actual code in it?

Comment: Okay. And since I'm obviously quite new to Objective C (this is a beginner tutorial after all), how would I go about writing that signature? I don't know what the return type should be, or for that matter, what parameters are being passed.

Comment: I tried to provide instructions on what the prototype (the proper name for the 'signature') in my answer above.  It's like the first line of the method, without the code body, and terminated with a ';'.

If a method is called via 'self', then the code is in the same class, and will (almost always) be in the same file, so you should have access to the method definition, and be able to see the return type and params.

Comment: I don't see the method definition anywhere in any of the files in the entire project, at all...

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, it's implicit in the tutorial example because it uses @properties and @synthesize, as @BoltClock says:

From the Housekeeping section of the tutorial: In the @implementation block of the class, tell the compiler to synthesize the accessor methods for the view controller:

@synthesize myViewController;

Comment: Unrelated, I feel sorry if anyone's username is "properties" or "synthesize" on SO cause they're probably getting bombarded here.

Comment: Hi cyclone, just copy and paste what Snips says (Probably it's -(void)setMyViewController(UIViewController*)aViewController;) (or something along that line) to your .h file where t says @interface myClass { /*here*/ }. I hope it's clear.